# How can I bulk rename files in a RAR or ZIP archive on the mac?

Tags: macos, zip, archiving, rename, rar

I have a set of archive files -- both zip and rar formats -- inside of which I need to rename some files.  Specifically, I want to do something like this:

```
for each archive file in a directory
    for each file in the archive
        if the file name matches the regular expression /(.* - [0-9]{2})([0-9]{2} - .)*/
            rename the file as \1-\2
```

The trick isn't so much in the generation of the new name; I can do that with either `bash` or `sed` or anything else. It's the set of commands to manipulate the files in the archives using `rar`/`unrar` or `unzip`/`zip`

(If it makes a difference, I'm re-formatting some CBR/CBZ files to get the double-page spreads to come up in the right order in SimpleComic -- it interprets page 0203 as page 203, which makes the story a bit hard to follow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way you'll find to do this is to unpack each archive, do the rename operation, then repack it.

On Linux, I could use a FUSE filesystem to have transparently decompressed archives, which I could operate on like regular folders, using a batch script to do all the renaming. I don't know if that particular FUSE filesystem exists for Mac.

Comment: Which fuse FS is that?

Comment: Here's a list of candidates: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=ArchiveFileSystems I haven't actually used any myself. I just said that I *could*.

Answer (score 2):

I look ate you example and I see PYTHON CODE :)

Really I think this should be the way to go.
I know this isn't stackoverflow.... but this is the only way I can see your problem solved.

Example code to extract all files:

```
import zipfile

a = zipfile.ZipFile("C:\\x.zip", 'r')
for i in a.namelist():         #Extract every file from it
     b = open("C:\\"+i, 'wb')
     b.write(a.read(i))
     #HERE YOU INSERT WHAT YOU WANT TO DO TO EACH FILE (b is the last file)
     b.close()
a.close()
```

Hope this helps

This page teaches how to [instal an unrar for the command line for MAC](http://www.robertvenema.nl/journal/archive/howto-command-line-unrar-on-mac-os-x/).

So you can do a script to unrar and a script to rar your files and call then from python, and make python change the names.

To execute an external script use:

```
import os;
os.system("path/scritname");
```

Comment: It does, but here's the trick; `zipfile` doesn't support RAR archives.

Comment: True, but there's a rarfile package which does: https://github.com/markokr/rarfile

Answer (score 0):

rar has a command line switch to rename files in the archive:

```
rar rn archive.rar filename newfilename
```

however the zip utility you're using does not. You'll need to extract, rename, and recompress as Ryan stated. There are other zip utilities for Mac which probably have this capability. I know 7-zip has supported renaming in archives [since 2.30 beta 25](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt), although I haven't checked if they support it from the command line. 7-zip is fairly extensive when it comes to command line options, so I'd assume it can.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this too, and I suspect the easiest thing to do is probably write a python script to do it, especially because you'll be dealing with both RAR and ZIP files.

It looks like there's not a particularly clean way to rename a file in a zip archive without unzipping all the files, renaming the ones you want to rename, and then zipping them back up, which is not really ideal.  However, I did stumble upon a OS/X utility called `zipnote` which does purport to do this:

[zipnote man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zipnote.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/zipnote)

It doesn't look terribly easy to use, but it might be worth looking into, and assuming it doesn't actually unzip the files itself it should be fairly easy to automate.  Meanwhile, the [command-line OS/X rar utility](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) does support renaming files inside of RAR archives via `rar rn foobar.rar oldname newname`.